# Setting multiple keys in Redis through Lua

Tags: redis, lua

I'm looking for an `INSERT` script counterpart in Redis where I want to set multiple keys at once.

```
SET foo bar
SET sun moon
SET fire water
...
```

How would a Lua script for the above look like as I couldn't find much help online.

Answer (score 3):

For a Lua script, I would do something like so:

```lua
for i=1, #KEYS do
    redis.call("SET", KEYS[i], ARGV[i])
end
```

Which in execution, would look like this:

```
EVAL 'for i=1, #KEYS do redis.call("SET", KEYS[i], ARGV[i]) end' 2 key1 key2 val1 val2
```

Note that `#KEYS` is not dynamically calculated, but rather the explicitly passed `numkeys` argument.

Additional validation could be added as necessary—asserting equal numbers of keys and args, for example—but I would strongly encourage doing most of that sanity checking client-side for performance.

---

If not using Lua, Redis has the command `MSET` to set multiple keys at once natively.

https://redis.io/commands/mset

Comment: I understand but I wanted a script that can be version controlled and stuff. Also, calling `MSET` has to happen through either Redis-cli or a language client (Node etc).

Comment: @Hyperbola updated my answer to include specific Lua solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am aware of the `MSET` family of commands. My general question was that what is the preferred way of scripting for redis, especially when it needs to be version controlled and used across multiple redis servers? Is it using any client of choice (Node, Python)?